# How to Enable SSL certificate for Default website in IIS7.5

Tags: ssl, iis-7

[image]

after enabling SSL Certificate IIS7.5 does not start Default site and above error occurred.

Comment: Without reviewing your server (certificate stores, IIS site bindings), it is impossible to tell what's up. IIS Manager is very fragile in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are configuring your host headers incorrectly.   For SSL to work properly you need to actually define the domain name it will use, or bind the site to *443 which means all ssl requests on that particular ip would hit that site.   Try doing a full restart, and if that doesnt work try and see if something is grabbing your SSL port.